# Option strict on disallows late binding error

Tags: vb.net

I am already using following code. (Following code is okey)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim FSO As Object = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FSO.deletefolder("C:\ATTACHMENTSSS")
End Sub

End Class
```

I did option strict is on.

Now I have this error: http://prnt.sc/afi2ws

How to solve that error?

Comment: Perhaps you should start using the NET Framework methods from System.IO

Comment: Option Strict On does not allow late binding - for good reason. In most cases you don't need to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the methods from the System.IO classes like [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\ATTACHMENTSSS")
    If di.Exists Then
       di.Delete(True)
    End If 
End Sub
```